# Can you access data in files stored on Onedrive using an Excel macro?

Tags: vba, excel, onedrive

I have a process that every day takes a day's worth of company data and inserts it into an Excel file which is then transferred via FTP to a folder on the company's Onedrive account. I want to be able to automatically amalgamate these daily files into a master file at the end of each month without having to go through one by one downloading copying and pasting.

Is there some clever VBA (or otherwise) way to tell excel to go to onedrive, open each of the 30/31 daily files and copy the contents of the DATA tab from them into the DATA tab of one central file? If not what would the macro look like if the files are already downloaded and saved on my computer?  That way I can at least save some copy-paste time.

Comment: Have you tried to assign a mapped drive designator *(like D: or E:)* to the OneDrive folder ??

Comment: @Gary's Student I can't alter the settings of the one drive is your suggestion something that I can do unilaterally?